# Find value smaller than average in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, average

I have this code:

```
SELECT username, first_name, last_name, NVL(salary,0) "salary"
FROM customer
WHERE NVL(salary,0) < AVG(NVL(salary, 0));
```

Trying to find out which users have lower salary than average and one user has no salary ("null" which I must convert to 0).

The last statement "avg(nvl(salary,0))" doesn't work and I can't for the life of me figure out why. If I replace the statement with the actual number of the average everything works just fine.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Do you get an error message - if so, what is it? Does the query run but provide the wrong result?

Comment: you need to select the average in a subquery and compare this result to the actual salary

Comment: I get this error message: "00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to pre-select the average:

```
select username,first_name,last_name,nvl(salary,0) "salary"
from customer
where nvl(salary,0) < (select avg(nvl(salary,0)) from customer);
```

You can use `avg` only in `select` and `having` clauses, that is why you have an error.

Also don't use `nvl` but use `coalesce` instead, this should be way faster on big data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly

Comment: I don't think you'd see much difference between coalesce and nvl in this case, but using coalesce would be a good habit to get into for future use cases.

Comment: @DavidAldridge what if you have an index on salary and amount of customers is 1Mi+?

Comment: @smnbbrv If you had an index on Nvl(salary,0), or Coalesce(salary,0) do you mean? Or maybe on (salary , 0) -- I don't think that an index on salary would do anything here, but I don't think an index on those expressions would be beneficial either to be honest. Maybe I misunderstand your intent though.

Comment: `index on customer(salary)` - this just won't be used with `nvl` but will be used with `coalesce`.

Comment: @smnbbrv In order to find the customer rows, or in order to optimise the avg(nvl(coalesce))? It won't be used for either, because in the former case something around of 50% of the rows need to be found, and for both the former and the latter rows with null salary won't be represented in the index anyway. I don't see a way of using such an index for this query,

Answer (score 4):

Here's a method using an analytic function:

```
select username,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       salary
from   (select username,
               first_name,
               last_name,
               nvl(salary,0) salary,
               avg(nvl(salary,0)) over () avg_all_salaries
        from   customer)
where  salary < avg_all_salaries
```

It makes it easy to also display the average of all salaries, should that ever arise.

Comment: well, personally I would find this example as an unnecessary explosion of a small query. If you really want to use / show `avg` later you can relocate the subquery from my example into `with` clause and make a join on the `customer` table. This helps to avoid repeating all the fields again and again  like you can see in this example

Comment: This answer is better, cuz it requires only one pass through the table, instead your variant with subquery. Performance is always more important the query size.

Comment: There is a potential with analytic functions that in some version memory management is not optimal, and if you partition in the analytic function you can get into swapping territory. Not in this case, but worth bearing in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username,first_name,last_name, NVL(salary,0) "salary"
FROM customer
WHERE NVL(salary,0) < (SELECT AVG(NVL(salary,0)) FROM customer);
```

This pretty easy to get.